# How do I install Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse. The package contains several files, one of which is `eclipse.exe`. Whenever I launch this, it starts Eclipse.

Is it supposed to be stand alone? Is there any way I can actually *install* Eclipse?

Comment: What do you expect from the **install** which unpacking can't do? Icons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's supposed to be stand alone.
No you can't `install` it in any normal sense.

From the [FAQ about installing Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_do_I_get_and_install_Eclipse?):

> To install Eclipse, all you do is unpack the zip file download in the desired directory. No further work is required (other than making sure you have a Java Runtime Engine installed). When you unzip the file, it creates a subdirectory called "eclipse", with multiple subdirectories under that. So, for example, in Windows you could unpack the zip file in the root directory (e.g., C:) and Eclipse would be installed in C:\eclipse. Note that installing Eclipse does not change the Windows registry.